# How am I able to return this variable that is block scoped?

Tags: javascript

```js
function F (v) {
    var v = v;
    this.fun = function f () {
            console.log(v);
    };
};

var i = new F(1); 

i.fun();
```

My question here is how is `i.fun()` able to return `v`?

**disclaimer**: I'm fairly certain my problem here isn't knowing what closures are. I.e. I know that `function f` can see `var v` in the `F` function. But what I'll try to show you is that we're not dealing with `F` anymore. We're dealing with the *object* that `F` returned and assigned to `i` on line 8.

As far as I can see:

`new F(1);` returns `{fun: function f(){console.log(v)}}`. It returns an *object.*
This object is assigned to `i`.
`i.fun()` returns the calling of `function f` which references `v` - but `v` is block-scoped in the constructor function so it can't see `v`. `v` didn't get transferred over to the object, `i` with something like `this.v = v`.

Comment: This absolutely is closures/lexical scoping. Calling `F` creates a new scope. `v` is defined in there, as is `f`. So `f`'s parent scope is that scope and hence it has access to `v`. The fact that the function is assigned to the property of an object is irrelevant. Maybe in simpler terms: If you define a function inside another function, the inner function has access to all variables defined/visible in the outer function. This is always true (in JavaScript), no matter the context.

Comment: @FelixKling But see how I break it down. `i` is simply `{fun: function f(){console.log(v)}}`. Where is `v` in this? `v` is back in the constructor function.

Comment: @FelixKling you can remove the declaration `var v = ...` and this code will work the same

Comment: @tonitone110 It can help you analyze your code in the console, [for example google chrome](https://gyazo.com/5ed3373bb6106ce7df95fb0439ce96cc)

Comment: Maybe this will help your confusion `console.log(i instanceof F)`

Comment: @charlietfl doesn't that just ascertain that I made `i` from a constructor function called `F`? I'm trying to figure out how a property of `i` (which is now an object) is able to return something that is not in `i` or the global scope. `v` is 'function scoped' in function `F`

Comment: @FelixKling I understand what you're saying but is it not the case that we're not even dealing with `F`? Like I say in the question, we're dealing with what `F` returned, which is: `{fun: function f(){console.log(v)}}`. Therefore, how is `function f` able to see `v` when `function f` is part of a brand new object?

Comment: `F` is a closure and `i` is an instance of `F`. Logging `i` to console won't show you variables inside F , only properties of it and I think that is confusing you. Just need to understand how closures work. The console can only show you so much

Comment: @charlietfl Right. `i` is an instance of `F` and on the console it also shows it's just an object. So how is one of the values of this object, `function f`, able to see `var v` way back in a constructor function?

Comment: You are confusing the limited capability of the console vs the functionality of using `new`. Again, logging that object is giving you impression it is a plain object but there is far more to it than a plain object

Comment: @FelixKling @charlietfl Thanks guys I will just try to summarise my issue like this. I know `function f` can see `v` when we are calling `function f` from the constructor function `F`. But it's my understanding `function f` has been copied over as a value in a brand new object, assigned to `i`. And it is this value we are returning when we type `i.fun();`. Therefore, how does this new `function f` see `v`?

Comment: Do some more research into "closures" and using "new". far more complexity going on than just "copy"

Comment: Thanks for your patience @charlietfl that was the kind of answer I was looking for. Are you aware of any resources you could direct me to to learn more about it? For now I will assume something like...an instance of a constructor function also has access to its constructor function (scope)...

Comment: If you do a `console.dir(i.fun)`, Chrome devtools will show you a "Closure" property (or something similar), which will list `v`. The fact that the function is assigned to an object property is irrelevant. You can return the function directly with the same result: `function F(v) { var v = v; return function f() { console.log(v); }}; `var i = F(1);`. In this example, `f` is identical to your example for all intents and purposes (`console.dir(i)`). The fact that you call `F` with `new` and that you assign `f` to a property is irrelevant for the relationship between `F` and `f`.